# React render model in sorted order on a field

Tags: reactjs

Below is my react script for rendering an html content.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';
import moment from 'moment';
import AppLink from '../containers/AppLinkContainer';
import { createReservationLink } from '../utils/link-creators';

export default class ReceiptListItem extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        className: PropTypes.string,
        children: PropTypes.node,
        model: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        const { className, children, model } = this.props;

        return (
            <AppLink to={createReservationLink({ reservationId: model.id })} className={cx('ReceiptListItem margin-top-3 padding-bottom-3 border-bottom-1', className)}>
                <figure className="ReceiptListItem-figure">
                    <img src={model.venue.thumb_image_url} alt={model.venue.about} />
                </figure>
                <div className="ReceiptListItem-content">
                    <div className="ReceiptListItem-contentInner">
                        <h3>{model.section.location}, {model.venue.name}</h3>
                        <p className="color-lightMuted">{moment(model.reservation_date).format('dddd MMMM Do')}</p>
                        <p className="color-lightMuted">Status : {model.reservation_status}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </AppLink>
        );
    }

}
```

This displays the list as is from the backend. I want to display this list in descending order of model.reservation_date.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Make your `reservation` prop an array and sort by date (utilizing `Array.proto.sort` and perhaps a lib like `moment` or simply comparing ISO date strings in vanilla JS). I bet `reservation` is an object now, fetched from BE?

Comment: Yes reservation is an object fetched from backend. Do you know the exact code to convert the object to array and sort it.

Comment: it's a litlte confusing now. You want to display a list of items (I suppose a list of reservations?), but you only get a single object from BE. You get only a single item of `reservation` or is the list you're referring to hidden somewhere inside the `reservation` object? Are you referring to `reservation.line_items` as the list?

Comment: My bad, I had put in the wrong code. Above is the entire file. I want to sort the model list based on reservation_date in descending order.

Comment: and model is still an object.

Comment: Ok, I see your comp. is called `ReceiptListItem`, can you provide the code for `ReceiptList` comp.? I suppose that's where the array is stored. You can't sort an `object` because there's nothing to sort it by since it's a single item.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I got the ReceiptListItem. It was sorted in ascending order. I changed it to descending. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to convert your object to array. Underscore do it beautifully in a single line:

```
var newArr = _(yourObject).toArray();
```

Second, sort your newArr using lodash/sortBy. Use reverse after sortBy to achieve descending order.

```
_.sortBy(newArr).reverse();
```