# reactjs - display records in sorted order based on date field mongodb

Tags: reactjs

Am fetching records from mongodb and displaying it in reactjs. I want to render those records in sorted order on date field. Please suggest me.

Am not using mongoes. Only Reactjs and mongodb.

```
class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { };
}

render() {
return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) => <SearchResults key={ item.id 
} item={ item } open={ this.props.open } />) }</tbody>);
}
}

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { };
}

render() {
return (
<tr onClick={ this.handleOpen } style={{color: 'blue',fontsize: '12',cursor: 
'pointer'}}>
<td>{ this.props.item.OrderNumber }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.Assignee }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.Status }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.OrderDate }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.CreatedDate }</td>
</tr>
);
}
```

Comment: please provide more information.  is your backend express? are you using mongooose? perhaps post a snippet of the component responsible for rendering the data.

Comment: Please find the code that i uploaded. Am using reactjs with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving data in JSON format, you convert it to an array and then sort is based on the your desired data field. You can use underscore, lodash sort of libraries to avail ready to use methods.

Edit:
See my another answer which shows how to convert object to array and sort it.

[React render model in sorted order on a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430195/react-render-model-in-sorted-order-on-a-field/45431572#45431572)

Answer (score 0):

you could sort the entries into a new array and render those...

```
class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        this.renderItems = this.renderItems();
    }

    renderItems() {
        // using slice to avoid mutation
        const items = this.props.items.slice().sort((a, b) => {
            return b.date - a.date; // or some other logic to determine if a and b should be swapped
        });

        items.map(item =>
            <SearchResults
                key={item.id}
                item={item}
                open={this.props.open}
            />
        );

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tbody>
                {this.renderItems()}
            </tbody>
        );
    }
}

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr
                onClick={this.handleOpen}
                style={{
                    color: "blue",
                    fontsize: "12",
                    cursor: "pointer"
                }}
            >
                <td>
                    {this.props.item.OrderNumber}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.item.Assignee}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.item.Status}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.item.OrderDate}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.item.CreatedDate}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. its not showing date field itself.